# How to select all messages Inbox Google?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

The new Google email application, [Inbox](http://www.google.com/inbox/) has just been released so I decided to try it.

I wanted to delete all my spam messages but I can't find a button to select all of them without clicking on each one.

Is it possible to select all messages at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Select All" feature is not available as of now in [Inbox by Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox) app. Nor this feature of multiple selecting of spam emails at once available in the [web version of Inbox by Gmail](http://inbox.google.com). Only [Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm) app has the `Empty Spam` option but not select all. You can also swipe to delete in the new version of Inbox app. But that won't make a big difference if you have hundreds of emails spammed to you.

[image: screenshot of spam folder]

Take a look at the [Features not implemented yet](http://gmail-miscellany.blogspot.in/2014/10/inbox-by-gmail-101.html#features) blog post section.

> Gmail or Inbox by Gmail?
>
> So, which one should you use? Most of the above can be reduced to just
>   a couple key points for each product. But remember that: `Inbox` is not simply a user-interface change
>   to Gmail, it as an entirely new product.

Gmail

- Customizable - multiple inbox formats and message organization options  -
- Flexible - many message attributes to manage e-mail

Inbox by Gmail

- Simple - easy to learn and use
- Consistent - the same user-interface on all platforms

> Of course there's no reason you can't use both. You could use Inbox on
>   a day-to-day basis, or on mobile devices, and then use Standard Gmail
>   for more complex activity like creating non-labeling filters, multiple
>   message selection, emptying Trash and Spam, etc. Gmail and Inbox by
>   Gmail are just tools and you should use whatever helps you manage your
>   e-mail the best.
>
> So feel free to continue to use Gmail, switch to Inbox, use both as
>   appropriate, or use neither if you prefer your installed e-mail
>   client. The choice is totally yours.[[Ref.](http://gmail-tips.blogspot.in/2014/10/inbox-by-gmail.html)]

**UPDATE** : This functionality is now available in Inbox by GMail as of 10th Sep 2015. Google has added an option to delete all spam messages in single click via the ["Empty Trash Now"](https://inbox.google.com/spam?cid=imp&pli=1) button. [Read here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+InboxbyGmail/posts/T7ucEQgpxTn).

As posted on Google Plus,

> Small update: You can now empty Trash and Spam in Inbox. Thanks to
>   everyone for your feedback requesting this feature.
>
> [image]

You can also do this in the webversion of [Inbox by Gmail's](https://inbox.google.com/spam) spam page. Clicking on the "Empty Spam now" clears up the spam folder. Note that spam left undeleted for more than 30 days are deleted automatically.

Comment: It's not available in the webversion too, I can't find it. But thanks. Do you know when this will be implemented?

Comment: Have no idea about it, only google knows about when it will be added. Only gmail has this feature right now and there are extension like [Smooth checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-checkbox-for-gmail/egkhfllhmjihbfnkikpnbeeakllbobjl?hl=en) but only works for gmail. Couldn't find anything which works on Inbox By Gmail yet. Well you can leave a suggestion on the review section on the play store app page.

Comment: I've just found out that it's possible to do a multiple selection of emails : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/AMKpXXLOoWA but still not all messages yet.

Comment: @Maxime Note: Those are for bundled messages(Social, Promotions, Updates etc). Unfortunately Spam messages cannot be added to bundled message automatically. So multiple deletion of messages for unbundled email(in this case spam) is not possilble. Only thing is we need to select every email which is in spam and select the Bin option which is time consuming. As [this message](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/inbox/AMKpXXLOoWA/Jf_MwhAbjZwJ) suggests, you can request this feature in the feeback option as they are tracking these requests and give us an update in the future. ;)

Comment: However I tried creating custom bundle filter to filter those spam message and add those email to the custom label bundled email. But the custom label which I created is displayed under the bundled inbox but doesn't have the option to swipe all at once. Only the pre bundled Inbox labels such as Purchases, Finance, Social, Updates, Forums have options to clear all the emails under that label at once.

Comment: Yeah, welcome to the world of half-implemented features which is called Google. I'm so pissed off that such a simple thing is not added since beginning of the Inbox. The product itself seems to not improve anymore. I think it'll soon be pushing up the daisies on the same cemetery on which Google Wave and Google Reader are buried.

Comment: @Maxime Thanks for the edit. I've updated the answer. It's good to have this option now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can now do a "shift select" style selection to select all the messages between two.

For example, if I have 6 messages in a row that I would like to delete (because they have been filtered or searched, etc), as below:

Message 1
Message 2
Message 3
Message 4
Message 5
Message 6

Then you can first, select Message 1 by clicking its checkbox. Then hold shift and select Message 6 by clicking its checkbox. All the messages between 1 and 6 should then also be selected.

Comment: You mean by hooking up an external keyboard?

Comment: This is the closest acceptable answer for the Inbox web interface.